# No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"carts", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am trying to create a simple add to cart with Ruby on Rails and I having an issue to display a simple link to cart that has the last id of the user that just added an item to the cart.
Simple I getting this error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"carts", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]
```

This is my link to the cart and it the place where I am getting the error

```
<%= link_to 'Cart', cart_path(@cart), class: 'header__cart_link' %>
```

Routs look same as they should be, I am calling it

```
resources :carts
```

In console rake routes

```
carts GET        /carts(.:format)                                                                         carts#index
                          POST       /carts(.:format)                                                                         carts#create
                 new_cart GET        /carts/new(.:format)                                                                     carts#new
                edit_cart GET        /carts/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                carts#edit
                     cart GET        /carts/:id(.:format)                                                                     carts#show
                          PATCH      /carts/:id(.:format)                                                                     carts#update
                          PUT        /carts/:id(.:format)                                                                     carts#update
                          DELETE     /carts/:id(.:format)                                                                     carts#destroy
```

Also, I am using a line_items controller to create a reference for the cart so that I making a relation of the product and cart in the line_items

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_cart, only: %i[show edit update destroy]
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :invalid_cart
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def index
    @carts = Cart.all
  end

  def new
    @cart = Cart.new
  end

  def create
    @cart = Cart.new(cart_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @cart.save
        format.html { redirect_to @cart, notice: 'Cart was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @cart }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @cart.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @cart.update(cart_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @cart, notice: 'Cart was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @cart }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @cart.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    # @cart.destroy if @cart.id == session[:cart_id]
    @cart.destroy
    session[:cart_id] = nil
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Cart was successfully emptied.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def empty_cart
    if !@cart.nil?
      redirect_to cart_path(@cart)
    else
      redirect_to cart_path(session[:cart_id])
    end
  end

  private

  def set_cart
    @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])
  end

  def cart_params
    params.fetch(:cart, {})
  end

  def invalid_cart
    logger.error "Attempt to access invalid cart #{params[:id]}"
    redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Invalid cart'
  end
end
```

and here the cart controller it self

```
  def create
    @cart = Cart.new(cart_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @cart.save
        format.html { redirect_to @cart, notice: 'Cart was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @cart }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @cart.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

In my application_controller.rb I handaling the set_cart

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  include CurrentCart
  before_action :set_cart
  # before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  before_action :store_session_data
  before_action :clean_session_cart

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    if user_signed_in?
      redirect_to main_app.root_url, alert: exception.message
    else
      redirect_to new_user_session_path, alert: exception.message
    end
  end

  protect_from_forgery

  protected

  def clean_session_cart
    Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    session[:cart_id] = nil
  end

  def store_session_data
    RequestStore.store[:session] = session
  end
end
```

and then I creating a `concerns` in the models current_cart.rb

```
module CurrentCart
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  private

  def set_cart
    begin
      @cart = Cart.find(params[:cart_id] || session[:cart_id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      @cart = Cart.create
    end

    session[:card_id] = @cart.id
  end
end
```

Comment: Check `@cart` is not null when generating the link

Comment: @emaillenin I can easily access to localhost:3000/carts/2 if the item was added to the cart. Otherwise is just failing.

Comment: in which view file you've this link `<%= link_to 'Cart', cart_path(@cart), class: 'header__cart_link' %>` ?

Comment: Can you run `rake routes` and tell us what you see?

Comment: @SikandarTariq it is in `view/layouts/_header.html.erb`

Comment: @shashwat what exactly I should look for? my cart route set as `resourses :carts` which giving me all of them, is it?

Comment: Sometimes, depending on your routes file, the helper functions for the URL can be a little different. `rake routes` will generally mention exactly what the name of the relevant helper function will be, so you can confirm it once.

Comment: Also, aren't you trying to access the `show` method in the controller? Why have you added the code for the `create` method? Can you share the code within the `show` method?

Comment: @shashwat I don't have `show` in cart controller. Also, I just updated the `rake routes` in question above

Comment: @shashwat I am using `before_action` to set a card to have a relation of `@cart = Cart.find(params[:id])

Answer (score 0):

`@cart` is not initialized for `view/layouts/_header.html.erb`.

> set cart in your application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_global_cart

  def set_global_cart
    @global_cart = current_user.cart || current_user.cart.create()
    //something similar & it will be better to use different name instead of @cart
  end
end
```

Comment: I just updated my question again, and I shared my `application_controller.rb` and `current_cart.rb` concern file with it. As you see I am already handling the @card id but apparently it doesn't work right

Comment: try `@cart = Cart.create!` in your set_cart method of `CurrentCart` module... maybe cart is not creating due to some validation failure

Comment: your option with `Cart.create!` I think start working, but now I am getting this `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Cart without an ID: app/controllers/concerns/current_cart.rb:8:in `set_cart'` which is `@cart = Cart.find(params[:card_id] || session[:cart_id])` do you have any other suggections how to fix it?

Comment: please use `byebug` and try to evaluate what is going wrong. it seems like you should use `params[:id]` instead of `params[:card_id]`

Comment: I made a typo, first of all, it should be cart not card. also, I will check it with byebug and come back with my research